# XSL - Create Multiple Tables According to The Different Values Of An XML Child Node

Tags: xml, xslt

I've tried to transform the following XML doc into multiple tables, according to the value of a specific child node. Here is how my XML looks like:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="AlbumsTranformedToXSL.xsl"?>
<!--<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="addCountryAttribute.xsl"?>-->

<Albums>
 <Album>
  <Name>Empire Burlesque</Name>
  <Artist>Bob Dylan</Artist>
  <Country>USA</Country>
  <Company>Columbia</Company>
  <Date>19880610</Date>
 </Album>
 <Album>
  <Name>Hide your heart</Name>
  <Artist>Bonnie Tylor</Artist>
  <Country>UK</Country>
  <Company>CBS Records</Company>
  <Price>9.90</Price>
  <Date>19880509</Date>
 </Album>
</Albums>
```

And here is my current XSL:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
        <body>
            <table border="2" bgcolor="transparent">
                <tr bgcolor="grey">
                    <th>Artist</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="Albums/Album">
                    <xsl:sort select="Date" />
                    <!--printing table-->
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Artist" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>

        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently my XSL transform the XML into one table, but i am trying to split it into several tables - a different table for each "Country" tag (i.e. a table for albums from the US, another one for albums from the UK etc.). How can I make it happen?

I've spent hours trying to implement several methods i've found, but nothing seems to work for me (probably due to my lack of XSL knowledge...). I will be really grateful for a little guidance here. Thanks!

Comment: So you want to group the `Album` elements by `Country` (and then create a table for each group), grouping has been treated here lots of times, you can also find examples in the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#grouping-examples or in any text book https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following template using the *Muenchian method* - an XSLT-1.0 way of grouping elements working well in *WebBrowsers* like *Firefox*, *IE* or *Chrome*:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="country" match="Album" use="Country" />

    <xsl:template match="/Albums">
        <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="Album[generate-id() = generate-id(key('country',Country)[1])]">
                <table border="2" bgcolor="transparent">
                    <tr bgcolor="grey">
                        <th>Artist</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('country',Country)">
                        <xsl:sort select="Date" order="ascending"/>   <!-- here you decide what elements are at the top -->
                        <!--printing table-->
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Artist" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>    
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above template does order your elements into two tables. One for each `Country` of the example. If you'd have more Countries, there would be more tables, of course. The order of the elements is decided by the `xsl:sort` in the `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!